# Exact resizing a chart in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, resize

I was trying to resize some charts in Excel using VBA. The code below does the job but there is a caveat: Excel 2016 reports the size of the resized charts as 5.21" * 9.02" instead of 5" * 9" as I would have expected. Any advice on how to exactly resize the charts to 5" * 9" would be highly appreciated. Please note that I don't have any constraint to preserve the aspect ratio.

Thank you.

```
Sub chartResize()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim chartWidthInInches As Double
   Dim chartHeightInInches As Double

   chartHeightInInches = 5
   chartWidthInInches = 9

   For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
       If ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Type = msoChart Then
          ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Height = chartHeightInInches * 72
          ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Width = chartWidthInInches * 72
       End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the sheet zoom setting at? 100% or some other percentage?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior happens only if the zoom setting is not 100%. At 100% Excel shows 5" * 9" after resizing. With your help I answered my question. Thank you.